# Absolute position of a stage in libgdx

Tags: camera, libgdx, stage

I have a camera and a stage in my project.
When I move up the camera, the stage follow it but I want the stage stay at the same place.

I would set the **camera** to the **stage** :
`this.stage.setCamera(camera);`

This worked before the update of **libgdx** 0.9.8 -> 1.0.1 but this function doesn't exist anymore.

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They added the Viewport stuff. See [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) artikle for more information.
The stage itself does not have any camera anymore. But the viewport of the stage has one.

This should solve your issue if you already use a viewport.

```
stage.getViewport().setCamera(cam);
```